# Getting 2 classes that know nothing of each other to share events in c#?

Tags: c#, forms, events, class, share

I have three classes, one class loads in a configuration file into memory for access later on.  My other class is the mainform.  What I am attempting to achieve is that when certain elements of the configuration class are loaded in they are added to a listview in the GUI (WindowsForm).

I know you can't access the GUI directly from the other non-mainform classes, which after reading I don't want to do anyway, so I have been attempting to fire events to say "config updated" that the mainform will listen for and update the listview when appropriate.  So I created a third class that defines the events and the delegates etc but in all the examples I've seen if different classes are calling the event they are all passed a shared instance of the event class.

Is this the way I should do things?  When I created the configuration class from the mainform class should I pass an instance of the event class?  Or is there a way for 2 classes that don't know anything about each other to share an event?

I've modified a microsoft example below to semi demonstrate what I'm needing.

```
    using System;

public class FireEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public FireEventArgs(string room, int ferocity)
    {
        this.room = room;
        this.ferocity = ferocity;
    }
    public string room;
    public int ferocity;
}

public class FireAlarm
{
    public delegate void FireEventHandler(object sender, FireEventArgs fe);
    public event FireEventHandler FireEvent;

    public void ActivateFireAlarm(string room, int ferocity)
    {
        FireEventArgs fireArgs = new FireEventArgs(room, ferocity);
        if(FireEvent!=null)FireEvent(this, fireArgs);
    }
}

public class FireEventTest
{

    public static void ExtinguishFire(object sender, FireEventArgs fe)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe ExtinguishFire function was called by {0}.", sender.ToString());
        if (fe.ferocity < 2)
            Console.WriteLine("This fire in the {0} is no problem.  I'm going to pour some water on it.", fe.room);
        else if (fe.ferocity < 5)
            Console.WriteLine("I'm using FireExtinguisher to put out the fire in the {0}.", fe.room);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The fire in the {0} is out of control.  I'm calling the fire department!", fe.room);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        FireAlarm myFireAlarm = new FireAlarm();
        FireAlarm fireAlarm = new FireAlarm();
        fireAlarm.FireEvent += new FireAlarm.FireEventHandler(ExtinguishFire);
        myFireAlarm.ActivateFireAlarm("Kitchen", 3);
        myFireAlarm.ActivateFireAlarm("Study", 1);
        myFireAlarm.ActivateFireAlarm("Porch", 5);
        return;

    }   
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think that I understand you fully, but you can have a class called EventDispatcher, make it Singleton if you want, and inside it have a public event

`ConfigurationElementLoaded(object sender, ConfigurationElementLoadedArgs args)`

and a public method to fire the event:

```
void FireConfigurationElementLoaded(ConfigurationElement element)
```

in which you fire the event.

Your mainForm can subscribe via the Singleton isntance : `EventDispatcher.Instance.ConfigurationElementLoaded += ...`

and your Configuration can fire the event with `FireConfigurationElementLoaded`.

If this answer doesn't help, please elaborate more what exactly you want to do...

Comment: I never thought about a singleton (d'oh).  

This sounds like the best way to fix my problem but I am actually wondering if my problem is due to bad code.  All I'm trying to do is update a listview with data from a separate class than the UI class/thread in the best way possible.  

I've found threads that suggest to raise events but I can't find examples on the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if the classes know nothing about each other at all i think it will be a little messy, but thats not really the case though right? The UI knows what event it wants to listen to.

This is absolutley fine though, ui can absolutly know about what its supposed to display, atleast via an interface. What you dont want is to have the business classes be dependant on the UI (you want an unidirectional flow of dependencies)

I would say either define an interface containing your events and implement it in `FireAlarm` or listen directly to the events in `FireAlarm`.

Also, its strictly speaking not the case the code outside the form cant be used inside the the form. its absolutley fine for the ui to listen to and use an event with a custom EventArgs written by you, including the `sender` object.

What really matter is what thread is running the code in question. As long as the UI is accessed from the UI thread (the thread that created the ui) you can run any code.

Is there a reason why the code you've posted doesnt work?

Comment: ok I lied a bit when I said they know nothing about each other at all.  The MainForm does create an instance of the configuration class.  The code above won't work because when "myFireAlarm" fires the event the "fireAlarm" listener doesn't receive the event, which I believe is due to them being separate instances of the FireAlarm class

Comment: ah, yes, that is because they are diffrent instances. you declare the event as static (just like other members) to have the event be, well, static :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a databindind on controls if you just want to update a content on UI of your windows form.

Create a data layer which holds an inormation of your config file and bind its properties to your interface controls. At the moment you change values of that properties databinding mechanism will care about updating your UI.

In genareal my opinion is: *if something already exist in framework you use 
(in this case .NET framework) that fits your needs, just use it, do not invent bycicle, cause someone else already suffered inventing it :)*

[DataBinding for WindowsForm example](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html)

Looking at all that events stuff I presumed that we are talking about WindowsForm application. If not, please precise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My actual problem is the communication between separate classes and the UI rather than the file and the UI but thanks for the suggestion.  I'll need to add data from other places such as sockets as well.  Sorry if I've misunderstood DataBinding.  Also, yes it is windows forms.

Comment: In DataBinding there is nothign related to "files", it's just about Data and Binding of that data. If you read from sockets, it depends on your architecture if you want do load a lot of data on UI and would like to implement something in async way or just load and show. But at least considering your post, I would say you need just: LoadData=> ShowOnUI, if Data changed => show changes on UI.